# how to pass json to highcharts

Tags: javascript, php, json

I need pass json to highcharts(javaScript)function to get data for series information so series contain two key name and data I need get data from json

```
<?php  $salename=json_encode($oSales); ?>
```

and code highcharts javaScript function

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'line'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Monthly Average Temperature'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Temperature (°C)'
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        line: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            },
            enableMouseTracking: false
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Tokyo',
        data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.4, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
    }, {
        name: 'London',
        data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
    }]
});
```

});

I need series get data from json varible inside php script
see example in [jsfiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-labels/)

very thanks

Comment: $('#container').highcharts(<?php echo $jsondata;?>) may be?

Comment: Thanks nbin but not work

Comment: what does your `$oSales` look like? And do you need to do it once, or dynamically? If the former, you can just plug the `json_encode` where `series: ` is, replacing `[{ name: 'Tokio', .... }]`

Comment: i need get data dynamically  i am try your solution but get output this [{"name":"Sale1-1"},{"name":"Sale2"}] in charts

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you want data that is coming from an ajax call.
Anycase, when you have a highcharts object you can set Data to it like this:

```
var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
chart.series[0].setData(aNewData);
```

In this case I'm assigning data to the first series of the chart.

Comment: I am try to send varible from php script ($salename) to series series: [
    {
    name:'.{{$salename}}.',
    data: [1, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.4, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
      },{
    name: '.{{$salename}}.',
    data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
      }]      but show data in chart this format [{"name":"Sale1-1"},{"name":"Sale2"}]